# The first image is showing popup, not others

Tags: javascript

I am listing posts on the homepage. There are images attached to every post. When someone clicks on the image, it pops up a message. The first image works fine, but others do not.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtn" class="text">
  <p>get access</p>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Please login</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have researched on StackOverflow and learned that in HTML there will be no same name ID element. I don't know how to implement the right codes.

Comment: Can we see a little more of your html, (multiple example of your buttons and their context)?

Comment: `The first image works fine, but others do not.` can you share that code?

Comment: @scagood, As per my HTML codes, when I click on "get access" text, it shows a popup message.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai, I have used these codes in WordPress loop.

Comment: Here is the HTML codes `<div class="imgcontainer">
           <img src="image_link" alt="poster" class="image" style="width:100%">
         <div class="middle">
         <div class="myBtn" class="text">
          <p>get access</p>
         </div>
          </div>
        </div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `querySelectorAll` to get more than one element that matches that selector.

you can use valid selectors including by id, tag name, attributes, classes, and more.

you get back an array of DOM elements, so you need to use `forEach` to set each and every button on its own.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.access-btn');
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
});

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.access-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.modal {
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Please login</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="myBtn" class="text access-btn">
  <p>get access</p>
</button>

<button id="myBtn" class="text access-btn">
  <p>2nd access</p>
</button>

<button id="myBtn" class="text access-btn">
  <p>3rd access</p>
</button>
```

Comment: Perfect! worked. I would upvote if I had enough rep. Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/fpx5hvvs/2/